# Android PieChart Using AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using AChartEngine to create Pie Chart on Android .It's OK.
But I want to remove "Line connect to Label from Pie ".

This is my code:

```
// Instantiating a renderer for the Pie Chart
    DefaultRenderer defaultRenderer  = new DefaultRenderer();       
    for(int i = 0 ;i<distribution.length;i++){          
        SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();       
        seriesRenderer.setColor(colors[i]);
        seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValuesDistance(0);
        seriesRenderer.setShowLegendItem(false);
        // Adding a renderer for a slice
        defaultRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);
    }

    defaultRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
    defaultRenderer.setClickEnabled(false);
    defaultRenderer.setPanEnabled(true);
    defaultRenderer.setAntialiasing(true);
    defaultRenderer.setShowLabels(true);
    defaultRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
    // Creating an intent to plot bar chart using dataset and multipleRenderer      
    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getPieChartIntent(getBaseContext(), distributionSeries , defaultRenderer, "AChartEnginePieChartDemo");     
    // Start Activity
    startActivity(intent);
```

Please see image to know clearly:

Now : https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwM1B.png

I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/olWB2.png

Please help me !

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

If you want to remove only the labels:

```
defaultRenderer.setShowLabels(false);
```

If you want to remove only the legend:

```
defaultRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
```

Comment: Yes ,And If you know another Chart API can do this ,Please tell me . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove only the labels: **renderer.setShowLabels(false);**
If you want to remove only the legend: **renderer.setShowLegend(false);**

Comment: You can also use renderer.setDisplayValues(true) for displaying the values on the slices.

Answer (score 0):

```
final CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("pie");

 for (int i = 0; i < Xaxes_value.size(); i++) {
            series.add(Xaxes_value.get(i) + "",
                    Long.parseLong(yaxes_value.get(i)));
        }


    List<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int[] colorr = { Color.parseColor("#56ADDB"),
            Color.parseColor("#F59331"), Color.parseColor("#73C83C"),
            Color.parseColor("#948D8B"), Color.parseColor("#E54273"),
            Color.parseColor("#FFD34E"), Color.parseColor("#2A86D6"),
            Color.parseColor("#00BFC0"), Color.parseColor("#95AC5F"),
            Color.parseColor("#FF8497") };

    for (int i = 0; i < yaxes_value.size(); i++) {
        colors.add(colorr[i]);

    }
    renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
    for (int color = 0; color < colors.size(); color++) {
        SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(colors.get(color));
        r.setDisplayBoundingPoints(false);
        // r.setDisplayChartValuesDistance(20);
        r.setDisplayChartValues(false);
        r.setChartValuesTextSize(18);
        r.setStroke(BasicStroke.SOLID);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }
    // renderer.isInScroll();

    renderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
    renderer.setPanEnabled(false);
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false); // set zoom button in Graph
    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(false);
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); // set background color
    renderer.setChartTitle("Pie Chart");
    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
     renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 100, 20, 15 });
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(20);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize((float) 30);
    renderer.setShowLabels(false);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(25);
    renderer.setDisplayValues(true);
    renderer.setStartAngle(90);
    GraphicalView mChart = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(getApplicationContext(), series,
            renderer);

    layout_graph.addView(mChart);
```